# Prolog HTTP dynamically add links to html

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'm new to prolog and declarative programming and I struggle to achieve the following.

I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.pathwayslms.com/swipltuts/html/index.html) and now would like to show a number of links on a page. Which links are to be displayed is dependent on certain facts / variables.

Here's my current code:

```
link_collection(Request) :-
http_parameters(Request,
[
    foo(Foo, [optional(true)])
]),
reply_html_page(
    [title('Dynamic Link Collection')],
    [
        a([href='/questionalice'], 'Question Alice'),       /* Should only show if has(investigate, body) is true */
        a([href='/questionbob'], 'Question Bob'),          /* Should only show if Foo = bar */
        a([href='/investigatebody'], 'Investigate Body')   /* Show always */
    ]
).
```

note that the number of "permutations" doesn't allow me to just "or" the `link_collection` statements. Also I would like the conditions to be arbitrarily complicated.

Comment: When writing HTML tags like `a` you need to enclose then in `html//1`.  Try `html([a(href='...', ...), ...])`, does that work for you?

Comment: no - reply_html_page automatically wraps it in html//1.. this code works fine, but the links are static and always show, irrespective of the conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question can be answered in a quite general context, that is, even without taking into account the concrete use case of HTTP.

The general question seems to be: How can I *dynamically* select a subset of some available options.

For this, suppose that you represent each link not simply as "itself", but rather as a **pair** of the form `Link-Condition`, with the interpretation that `Link` should only be included *if* `Condition` is **true**.

Let us first consider the **conditions** we want to express, and define *when* they are true. Importantly, your conditions also depend on the value of `Foo`, so this has to be taken into account:

```
is_true_with_foo(_, has(investigate, body)) :- has(investigate, body).
is_true_with_foo(Foo, Foo = bar)            :- Foo = bar.
is_true_with_foo(_, true).
```

So, this describes *when* a particular condition is true, also depending on the value of `Foo`.

Now, your sample conditions can be represented as follows:

```
links_conditions(Foo,
    [
        a([href='/questionalice'], 'Question Alice')-has(investigate, body),
        a([href='/questionbob'], 'Question Bob')-(Foo = bar),
        a([href='/investigatebody'], 'Investigate Body')-true
    ]).
```

To describe a *subsequence* of a list, consider using a DCG ([dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)).

For example:

```
links_subset([], _) --> [].
links_subset([L-Cond|Ls], Foo) -->
        (   { is_true_with_foo(Foo, Cond) } ->
            [L]
        ;   []
        ),
        links_subset(Ls, Foo).
```

You can now call:

```
?- links_conditions(Foo, LCs0),
   phrase(links_subset(LCs0, no), LCs).
```

and obtain, in `LCs` the remaining links. In this case:

```
LCs = [a([href='/questionalice'], 'Question Alice'),
 a([href='/investigatebody'], 'Investigate Body')].
```

So, we can *use* the resulting links in our reply:

```
link_collection(Request) :-
        http_parameters(Request, [foo(Foo, [optional(true)])]),
        links_conditions(Foo, LCs0),
        phrase(links_subset(LCs0, Foo), LCs),
        reply_html_page([title('Dynamic Link Collection')], LCs).
```

Note how `Foo` is passed along in these predicates.

P.S.: Your example snippet has elementary syntax errors, so I doubt that your code works in any way.

Comment: very interesting attempt, I will study it in detail and evaluate it tomorrow. Just wondering: what  syntax errors in my snippet are you referencing? I closely followed the tutorial, and my code, which is a less general version of the original snippet that I posted, works perfectly well. In fact I already came across a solution using DCGs and html includes using `\include` however your solutions seems more elegant.

Comment: There are 2 syntax errors in your snippet, in the second and third link representation. The first syntax error occurs at: `a([href='/questionbob']), 'Question Bob')`. Note the (second) closing `)` which has no matching `(`! The same error is present in the representation of the third link.

Comment: whops, yeah that must have slipped in due to copy and paste when designing the example snippet.

Comment: After trying the solution, I'm wondering if you see a way to use an arbitrary amount of condition variables like Foo?

Comment: Sure! Please file a separate question for this, I will answer it there.

Comment: actually, I managed to design a DCG which accepts a condition of the form `(Cond1; Cond2, Cond3)` as an argument. It will be true if cond2 and cond3 or cond1 is true. I don't even have to pass the Variables of the conditions to the DCG. I'm not 100% sure why  this works or if this has any side effects, but it seems to do everything I need for now. I'm accepting this answer.

Comment: Search for "Prolog meta interpreter" to see why this works! I think a systematic and comprehensive introduction to modern Prolog will be useful for you to solve such more complex tasks.